# ng build --prod bundle size has much bigger size than ng serve --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a strange problem. When running project with

```
ng serve --prod --aot=true
```

the main.bundle size is as on the picture via Chrome Dev tools
[image]

but when building with ng build --prod --aot=true and running on server main bundle size:
[image] 
Could you please tell me what is the reason of that? Having main.js 5.3 mb is very big.
ng build --prod main size is almost 5 times bigger than ng serve --prod.
 I think there it is because of problem. 
Angular: 5.2.2 
Angular-cli: 1.7.4

Comment: If you install `source-map-explorer` https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer 
and run it, you will have visual representation of the bundles used, this should give you some clue

Comment: Hi but chrome tools shows required info as in above photos

Comment: `ng serve --prod main size is almost 5 times bigger than ng build --prod` could you be bit specific? in your question, you have stated the opposite

Comment: @Vikas . I am very sorry. It is revised now.

Comment: @Vikas thanks so much for mention source-map-explorer. I saved a lot with it. But again  ng serve --prod main size is almost 5 times bigger than ng build --prod

Comment: I wasn't the one who mentioned to go for source-map explorer it's @mxr7350 apart from it I am unable to reproduce to the same and there is not much documentation provided on `ng serve --prod` yeah `aot` flag is not required `--prod` means it's `aot` by default

Comment: Thanks anyway . Yes I know aot is default in Angular 5 but to avoid unnecessary questions whether aot is turned or not, I wrote this way.